# where can i find wso2 source code

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to find wso2 source in particular for the following class:
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.doGetUserClaimValues(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:2583)

I googled an svn repo, but it didn't got changes since 2012, has only branches for 3.x (I am using 4.6.0) and the lines do not match.

I found a github repo (or repos) but there seems to be no org.wso2.carbon.user.core package there, only org.wso2.carbon.user.mgm, but this is not what I am looking for.

Any ideas where wso2 source code and in particular the user store code is located?

regards

Leon

In particular I am looking for following lines:

```
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.doGetUserClaimValues(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:2583)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getUserClaimValues(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:556)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getUserClaimValues(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:550)
```

Comment: I found a file with similar name on github: https://github.com/wso2/platform/blob/6792148f1fba4b852e9ced622749bea189c8bb19/components/user-stores/org.wso2.carbon.user.store/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/store/common/AbstractUserStoreManager.java but it doesn't match the lines that I see in exception stacktraces:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's located here: 
https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.2.0/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/4.2.0/

You may also want to look at the patches (up to patch0004, only if they contain updates to the user core):
https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.2.0/patches/

You can find the carbon platform version (and also patches) for each product by looking at the release matrix, and then search the repo for the sources. 
http://wso2.com/products/carbon/release-matrix/

(IS 4.6.0 is released with carbon 4.2.0 and also there's patch004 is released with that version.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I figured the 4.2.0 out but i was lost between different svn and github locations. Is github the future location?

Answer (score 0):

It can also be found on Github: https://github.com/wso2/product-is starting version 5.1.0